# LD: does --export-dynamic imply --whole-archive for a static lib if any of it's symbols are referenced?

Tags: gcc, linker

My main executable links with a static library whose symbols need to be available for dynamic libraries loaded through dlopen(). I understand that I need to use `-Wl,--export-dynamic,--whole-archive` flags to make it work. However there are many libraries specified on the link command, some maybe unused, and  I'm having difficulties applying `--whole-archive` selectively to the needed library through cmake within the current build infrastructure. What I'm seeing is that if only `-Wl,--export-dynamic` is used and the executable calls a function in the static library of interest, then the whole library gets included to the same effect of specifying `--whole-archive` for it, which is exactly what I need. Can I rely on this behavior to implicitly impose --whole-archive on libs whose symbols are referenced by the executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm seeing is that if only -Wl,--export-dynamic is used and the executable calls a function in the static library of interest, then the whole library gets included to the same effect of specifying --whole-archive for it, which is exactly what I need.

This isn't supposed to happen, and it is very likely that you are mis-interpreting what you see.

Example:

```
// foo.c
int foo() { return 42; }

// bar.c
int bar() { return 24; }

// main.c
int main() { return foo() - 42; }

gcc -w -c foo.c bar.c main.c
ar ruv libfoobar.a foo.o bar.o

gcc -Wl,--export-dynamic main.o -L. -lfoobar

nm a.out | egrep ' (foo|bar)'
000000000000113c T foo
```

As you can see, the whole `libfoobar.a` was *not* included in the executable. Contrast with:

```
gcc -Wl,--export-dynamic main.o -L. -Wl,--whole-archive -lfoobar -Wl,--no-whole-archive

nm a.out | egrep ' (foo|bar)'
0000000000001147 T bar
000000000000113c T foo
```

**Update:**

> if I add a function `foo1()` to `foo.c` it is pulled in, but it also happens regardless if `--export-dynamic` is supplied.

That is expected: the linker doesn't "split" a single `.o` file -- you get all or nothing.

You can change this behavior by using `-ffunction-sections` (and `-fdata-sections` for a good measure) at compile time and `-Wl,--gc-sections` at link time.

The cost is increased `.o` size and longer link time. The benefit is smaller executable.

Comment: Thanks, I see the same with your example. However if I add a function foo1() to foo.c it is pulled in, but it also happens regardless if --export-dynamic is supplied. Which makes me think the false positive I observed may have to do with the fact we use unity builds.

Comment: I checked the .a in question and it was in fact built from a single fused .cpp file, so I suppose I just got  lucky based on what you say, it's fragile but perhaps acceptable as a band aid fix for my purposes, need to ponder...

Comment: @VladG If the answer completely answered your question, please accept it. We work for the brownie points here :-)